# Make <a> to fill out the whole <li> tag

Tags: html, css

I read a lot of questions and answers. But nothing works for me.

The `a` should fill out the whole `li`. It should be responsive that's why I use `padding: 3%`.

I try to set `a { display:block; }` and I try to give it the `padding`. But nothing works great.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's obvious that `a` doesn't fill the `li`, since you set a padding on the `li` element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want but have you tried putting the **a** tag outside of the **li** element?

Edit: Simplified the answer

Example:

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
ul li a {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't do this. `li` are the only children of the `ul` tag

Comment: Sure you can, and as you saw, it worked. However it is not the best way. Check the updated answer, I changed it a little.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}
a{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid green;
      padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

hey use this

Answer (score 0):

Because you should use `margin` instead of `padding`. `a` doesn't fill out the whole `li` because `padding` adds additional spacing **inside** `li`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 3%;
}

a {
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 3% padding on the `li` elements is calculated from the container (in this case: window) width. Remove it and you get what you want:

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  float: left;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:0;
}
a{
  display: block;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```